# Parcel + Babel not transpiling ES6 from node_modules?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, transpiler, parceljs

I can't seem to get Babel to work with Parcel, although the presets are being installed automatically. It works locally and in Chrome, but it's not transpiling node_modules es6 files, so the output still has `const/let/...` and it cannot run in Safari.

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env","@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

(I've also tried the `env` and `react` ones).

package.json scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html",
    "build": "parcel build index.html",
```

Why would this be?

Full package.json (note this is after messing around in order to try to get it working)

```
{
  "name": "my-react-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html",
    "build": "parcel build index.html"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "browserslist": "^4.3.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "node-sass": "^4.10.0",
    "pinyin": "^2.8.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.1",
    "react-notifications": "^1.4.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cssnano": "^4.1.7",
    "sass": "^1.14.3"
  }
}
```

Still getting .js files with `const`, `let`. Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution to it from https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/1655#issuecomment-425593377

```
// .browserslistrc.packages
node 10.11

// package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "npm-run-all -p \"postinstall:*\"",
    "postinstall:p-retry": "cpy --rename=.browserslistrc .browserslistrc.packages node_modules/p-retry",
    "postinstall:query-string": "cpy --rename=.browserslistrc .browserslistrc.packages node_modules/query-string"
  }
}
```

Add a `postinstall:package-name` for every npm package that you need to add transpilation (in my case, `pinyin`) and run `npm run postinstall` after every `npm install`. Babel should now also transpile that npm package!